# Conversion from ReactJS Javascript to TypeScript Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am looking at an older React class that is written in JS.  The class in JS references 'this.element' which is not something that intrinsically exists in a typescript class that extends React.Component.   I'd love some direction on what 'this.element' is referencing and how to use it in the new TS Component model.  TYIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the property on the class:

```
 class SlideDownTransition extends React.Component {
    element: React.Component;

    /*...*/
 }
```